# Wifi multicast stream bandwidth limit

Tags: wifi, multicast

i am doing a project with multicast video streaming. The problem i am facing is, in 802.11b and 802.11g WiFi modes the multicast streaming band width is limited to 1Mbps. But the video have a bitrate of 2Mbps. after some search i found that the multicast streaming works on the lowest speed available. since the lowest speed for 802.11b and g is 1 Mbps,It is capped to 1 Mbps. So i was wondering is there anyway i could remove the bandwidth limitation.

Comment: What access point are you using?

Comment: The access point is a developed one using TI's wl1273l module and some Linux hardware's. Access point is created by the  Linux (configuring the hostapd ).

Answer (score 0):

For some cards,the broadcom b43 driver works if transmitting from the access point, and the basic rate is pegged to higher rates in hostapd.conf

So far, the only card I have seen work is inside 10 year old laptops such as the AMD Turion based gateway 64xx line.